# Javascript/jQuery search json for a string then run a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I need to run a function matchFound() if a string is found in an external json file.

This is what I have so far:

```
function init(){
   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=50&callback=?&q=http://www.domain.com/feed.rss",
      dataType: "json",
      success: parseData
   });
}

function parseData(data){
var string_to_find = "Hello World!";
  // look into the data and match the string
}

function matchFound(str, string_to_find){
    alert('Match found in string - '+ str +'\r\n While looking for the string- '+ string_to_find);
    return true;
}

function matchNotFound(){
    alert('No Match found!');   
}
```

But I don't know how to parse the Json data and search for a string.

I have this for XML (thanks @Ohgodwhy) but not sure how to translate for json

```
function parseXml(xml){
    var string_to_find = "Hello World!";
    $(xml).find('title').each(function(){
        var str = $(this).text();
        if(str.indexOf(string_to_find) > -1){
            if(matchFound(str, string_to_find)){
                return false;   
            }
        }

    });
}
```

The search location within the variables is: responceData > feed > entries > [0] or [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ro8dp.png) or [2] etc > contentSnippet

I only need to match the first 10 characters.

If a match is found then run the funciton matchFound() or if not found run the function matchNotFound()

Any help with this is very much appreciated.

C

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to iterate json recursively and then search for the string

```
function parseData(data){
var string_to_find = "Hello World!";
var is_found = iterate(data , string_to_find);
if(is_found === true){
      matchFound(JSON.stringify(data), string_to_find);
}else{
      matchNotFound(string_to_find);
}
  // look into the data and match the string
}

    function iterate(obj , string_to_find) {
    for(var key in obj) { // iterate, `key` is the property key
        var elem = obj[key]; // `obj[key]` is the value
         console.log(elem, string_to_find);
        if(typeof(elem)=="string" && elem.indexOf(string_to_find)!==-1) { 

            return true;
        }

        if(typeof elem === "object") { // is an object (plain object or array),
                                       // so contains children
           return iterate(elem , string_to_find); // call recursively
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Should `var is_found = iterate(obj , string_to_find);` be `var is_found = iterate(data , string_to_find);` ?

Comment: This is looking in title right? how do I look in `responceData > feed > entries > [0] or [1] or [2] etc > contentSnippet`

Comment: I need to loop through `entries` in the variable `contentSnippet` can that be done?

Comment: in that case you just have to remove the condition '"key === "title"' & write if(typeof(obj[key]) === "string" && obj[key].indexOf(string_to_find)!==-1)

Comment: Thanks... I always get `'No Match found!'` even though the string is difinitely in json file. any ideas? I have exactly what your posted.

Comment: post your json response here

Comment: check now .. added return in  ...  return iterate(elem , string_to_find); // call recursively

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48162/discussion-between-anup-singh-and-cybercampbell)